# fetch data from sql into php array returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to json_encode the data that was fetched from SQL, however, when I stored it into PHP array, it didn't return any value. Is there any code that I am missing or are there limits to the array?

I tried json_encode() inside a loop but I need angular 4 to read the json file that was encoded from the php file. Also, I tried to check if the loop was working and it fetched the 56 rows from SQL but when I put it into the PHP array, the array was displaying a blank PHP file.

/location.php (TRY1)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM api_locations";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$outp = array();
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $location = $data['loc_name'];
    $feature = $data['feature'];
    $lat = $data['lat'];    
    $lng = $data['lng'];
    $desc = $data['description'];
    $hrs = $data['hrs'];
    $min = $data['min'];
    $rating = $data['rating'];
    $max_b = $data['budget_maximum'];
    $min_b = $data['budget_minimum'];


    $outp[] = array( 
        "location" => $location,
        "feature" => $feature ,
        "lat" => $lat ,
        "lng" => $lng ,
        "description" => $desc ,
        "hrs" => $hrs ,
        "min" => $min ,
        "rating" => $rating ,
        "budget_maximum" => $max_b ,
        "budget_minimum" => $min_b ,
    );

}   
echo json_encode($outp);
}
```

or i did the while loop the other way:

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$outp[] = $data;
}
```

NOTE: The $outp is still empty when doing json_encode.

I expect the output will be like this.

> {"id":"1","loc_name":"Robinsons
>   Magnolia","lat":"123.1321","lng":"12.213","feature":"Shopping","description":"Happy
>   place to
>   shop","hrs":"1","min":"30","rating":"4","budget_maximum":"5000","budget_minimum":"100"}

...

> {"id":"56","loc_name":"CHICHIHC","lat":"213.1213","lng":"12.23131","feature":"Entertainment","description":"Good place to make
>   kalokohan","hrs":"1","min":"30","rating":"4","budget_maximum":"100","budget_minimum":"50"}

But the real output was blank.

I also tried to do this

```
$sql = "SELECT *
     FROM api_locations WHERE id<=9";
```

And this works. totally! but when it exceeds from 9. still not working.

Comment: It seems the query is returning empty result, could you print the value of `mysqli_num_rows($result)`?

Comment: When you modify your query you already have your wanted result. Instead of SELECT *, change to SELECT loc_name AS location, do this for all fields you want. then  for the result do  mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: @Zendy i also tried it before and it returns 56.

Comment: @LukStorms I also tried putting the echo inside, it works but when i use get request in my angular 4, it still return empty values.

Comment: @Grumpy Thank you for the suggestion but it is still empty.

Comment: can you print num_rows `echo mysqli_num_rows($result);` ?

Comment: @NaveedRamzan yes. it returns 58.

Comment: A comment related with the output, this line `"budget_maximum" => $min_b` shouldn't be `"budget_minimum" => $min_b`?

Comment: @PiggieSwear ok replace your while line `while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ` instead of $result->fetch_assoc()...

Comment: @Miguel oh i see. Thanks.

Comment: @NaveedRamzan Thanks but it returns same result

Comment: OK send me your file at ping@naveedramzan.com and that one table sql.

Comment: And last thing @PiggieSwear, I use your code, replicate the DB, with only this addition on the code `$con = mysqli_connect('192.168.99.100', 'user', 'pass', 'schema');`, and I am having this results:

`[{"location":"sdfasd","feature":"fsdfsd","lat":"23","lng":"23","description":"sfsdfs","hrs":"23","min":"32","rating":"23","budget_maximum":"32","budget_minimum":"23"},{"location":"asdfasd","feature":"afdafsd","lat":"32","lng":"432","description":"fsdfasdfas","hrs":"23","min":"32","rating":"43","budget_maximum":"423","budget_minimum":"423"}]`

So I would say the problem is on the DB side.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks. I tried printing the $data, all of them were queried so i'm not really sure what the problem is. I also limit the rows into 9 that can be fetched. it totally works but when it exceeds 9, it is empty again.

Comment: Guys I tried printing json error and it seems the problem was this 'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'. Thanks for all the help.